# What does "to draw a check" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, idioms, idiomatic-language

This is from a native speaker teacher who tells about classroom management, basically how to behave towards students and teach. She says:

*They know you actually care about them. it's funny you really will be fine because students know who really cares and who's just two years from retirement and drawing a check or whatever you can't fool students.*

The expression **"draw a check"** sounds interesting. I looked it up but it did not make sense, because it is usually about writing cheques, so I can't be sure about its meaning, as the teacher won't be writing a check at the time of retirement.

So, I wonder if it means the teacher will be given a cheque by the employer at the time of retirement to convert it to a lump sum money at the time of retirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Drawing** a check does not mean writing a check, it means *receiving* or *depositing* one.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/draw

> 7 d. to receive regularly or in due course: *draw* a salary

What the speaker is saying is that the teacher who is two years from retirement is only there to receive checks (and no longer actually cares about the students).

Comment: 'Drawing a check' is an exclusively American English expression, and 'check' is the American spelling of 'cheque' (British).

Comment: Yes, draw a check is receive a check **on a regular basis** (present simple).

Comment: Note also that in the UK cheques are virtually obsolete. They are still used on occasion, but you can't 'spend' them like in the past. No retailer will accept payment by cheque. Most stores stopped taking them in about 2007/8 or so. I was last paid [salary] by cheque in the mid 90s.

Comment: @Tetsujin  They're becoming very uncommon in the US too.  When the speaker talks about a teacher "drawing a check", it's almost certainly metaphorical; [about 96% of Americans are paid by direct deposit now.](https://www.nacha.org/content/how-direct-deposit-works)  I know Europeans think that it's all stone knives and bearskins on this side of the pond, but it's not *all* like that.  :-)

Comment: & I thought you guys were only just getting the hang of chip & pin… which is also falling out of favour over here in favour of such as Apple/Google Pay [I don't think I've chip & pinned in 4 or 5 years now] :P You *can* still use cheques over here, just not for retail. If you are sent one, your phone's bank app can scan it to pay it in.

Comment: We never really adopted chip & pin, but chip & signature was and still is big.  Things depend a lot on where you're shopping.  At a modern store in a city, you're likely to be able to use Apple/Google Pay.  A small store out in the sticks, not so much.  I don't know how many retailers are willing to accept checks these days; I'll have to ask my friend who owns a grocery store.  And we too have mobile bank apps that will scan checks.  The last time I used a check was when I bought real estate, but real estate transactions are kind of their own special world, at least over here.

Comment: Interesting. We've never had chip & signature at all. Signatures vanished along with the paper 'carbon-triplicate' thingies in about 2005, as chip became mandatory in all cards at that time. NFC 2007, but I don't think it was common until maybe 2010. It's been mandatory for some things for 5 years or more. You can't get on a bus in London without an NFC method of some sort, debit, phone or pre-pay. They haven't taken cash in a long long time, idk the date exactly. [btw, this is fascinating to me, how different countries adopted different standards.. even though we went off topic ages ago ;))

Comment: Also, covid drove the small retailer to NFC. You would be very hard-pressed to find even the smallest corner shop that didn't have an NFC payment handset these days. A lot of pubs/bars went cashless too, NFC only. Many people have simply stopped carrying cash now, driving NFC even harder. I have an emergency 20 in a holder on my keyring for if I'm ever stuck, but I don't even carry my wallet most of the time, just my phone. I think I first bravely declared mid 90s that I only carry cash for 'beer & taxis'… not even that nowadays ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin  I asked my grocery-owning friend, "Do people still try to pay with checks, and do you accept them?" and he said someone tries to pay with a check about once a year.  They do not accept checks, because they're just not set up to do it, and the person usually gets sniffy about it (not surprising; anybody still trying to buy groceries with a check here is definitely out in left field to begin with).  Cash is still widely accepted, but not on mass transit systems.  NYC buses and subways still accept their own swipe card but are trying hard to get everybody to move over to an NFC system.

Comment: My last cheque book in its entirely was used to pay one service garage who look after my vehicles, across a decade. Since one of the owners retired, the other now just likes cash. He doesn't even own a mobile phone. That is very, very much an outlier this day & age. Supermarkets now have separate areas where cash is still accepted, the majority of tills are NFC/chip&PIN. Train/tube [subway] have areas in stations you can still buy tickets with most payment methods [but not cheque], which then act as NFC once on the system. Mainly used by tourists. [I'm in London, we get a lot of tourists;)